# C# VSTO Excel Determin Comment Selection

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto, office-addins

I have created a VSTO excel plug-in, which is supposed to store a comment text in a database each time the comment has been changed.

(I'm giving you the code example in VBA since usually this is where I test initial ideas first)

When a comment is selected TypeName(Selection) returns “TextBox”
[image]

so what I initially thought would work is to put it into Workbook_SheetSelectionChange:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If TypeName(Target) = "TextBox" Then
    'let the user enter or change the comment
    'once the user has done that and changes the selection
    'trigger the save option to DB
  End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that selecting the comment does not trigger Workbook_SheetSelectionChange. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: You are talking about a "comment", then `TypeName(Target) = "TextBox"` should be about a sheet `Form` Text box.  Now, if such a text box is involved, what do you try doing? Then, why do you use such a type and not an ActiveX one? If you insist keeping it and associate a macro to the object/shape, you can identify it using `Application.caller` and then extracting its `Text`. But, if you simple click on it, it will  not be edit and call the assigned macro. So, you have to right click it, modify the text, go out and then click on it. But this looks like a strange process...

Comment: I do mean an actual comment to my surpise it clearly is a TextBox object (added screenshot to my Question for better understanding). And yes just as in a TextBox there is the right click option "Edit Text". The user will add many comments so any of those would need to be assosciated with that macro. Which brings us to another problem the option to assign a macro to a comment is not available.

Comment: How do you insert the text box object? If as I supposr, right clicking it offers this possibility...

Comment: Well the comment is of type TextBox but adding it is done by clicking a cell then right click it and select "New Note". 

Note that historically `Notes` used to be called Comments which is why VBA still calls them as such while the new "Comments" are called `CommentThreaded` in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA I'd check the cell comment content before and after leaving the cell as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Dim lastAddress As String
Dim cmtAddress As String
Dim cmtText As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
            cmtAddress = .Address
            cmtText = .Comment.Text
        Else
            If cmtAddress <> vbNullString Then
                If Range(cmtAddress).Comment.Text <> cmtText Then
                    MsgBox "comment changed in cell '" & cmtAddress & "'"
                End If
                cmtAddress = vbNullString
            
            Else
                If Not Range(lastAddress).Comment Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "comment added in cell '" & lastAddress & "'"
                End If
            End If
        End If
        
        lastAddress = .Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm currently trying this out there is a minor error to be bugged out but this actually looks like the way to go. I'll mark this as the answer once I get it to work for me and will post the final code. 

It's a shame that selecting a comment or entering it for edit does not directly trigger the event.

Comment: Nice idea. Voted it up even if it does not cover all possible situations. I did not even understand what OP wants...

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code event, covering more situations. But **all credit must go to @user3598756**, who had the brilliant idea. From the beginning *I even did not understand your question*...

```
Option Explicit

Dim lastAddress As String
Dim cmtAddress As String
Dim cmtText As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                If cmtAddress <> vbNullString Then
                    If Not Range(cmtAddress).Comment Is Nothing Then
                        If Range(cmtAddress).Comment.Text <> cmtText Then
                            MsgBox "Comment changed in cell '" & cmtAddress & "', " & vbCrLf & _
                            "(""" & Range(cmtAddress).Comment.Text & """ instead of """ & cmtText & """)."
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                If Not lastAddress = "" Then
                        If Not Range(lastAddress).Comment Is Nothing Then
                            MsgBox "Comment added in cell '" & lastAddress & "'" & vbCrLf & _
                            "(""" & Range(lastAddress).Comment.Text & """)."
                        End If
                End If
                cmtAddress = .address
                cmtText = .Comment.Text
        Else
                If cmtAddress <> vbNullString Then
                    If Not Range(cmtAddress).Comment Is Nothing Then
                        If Range(cmtAddress).Comment.Text <> cmtText Then
                            MsgBox "Comment changed in cell '" & cmtAddress & "', " & vbCrLf & _
                            "(""" & Range(cmtAddress).Comment.Text & """ instead of """ & cmtText & """)."
                        End If
                    End If
                    cmtAddress = vbNullString
                Else
                   If Not lastAddress = "" Then
                        If Not Range(lastAddress).Comment Is Nothing Then
                            MsgBox "Comment added in cell '" & lastAddress & "'" & vbCrLf & _
                            "(""" & Range(lastAddress).Comment.Text & """)."
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
        End If
        
        lastAddress = .address
    End With
End Sub
```

The idea is that the event should also catch the cases of next selection having such a 'text box', too. And something to prevent the empty addresses when the process starts...